# How did I start with more than 100 reputation on meta.quant.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

I logged into http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com for the first time, and saw that my reputation (on the meta site's bar) was 180,

[image]

which was my reputation on the main site, http://quant.stackexchange.com, at the time. I figured perhaps certain sites opt to use a single meter for both their main and meta reputation. But then, not long after, several of my edits on the *main* site were approved, gaining me +6 reputation:

[image]

**Yet my *meta* reputation stands the same: 180. What's going on?** Do you just *start* with whatever reputation you had on the *main* site? But then, can't you cheat the system by clearing all associations or something?

I must be missing something. Please enlighten me :-)

Comment: I think we need an `faq-proposed` version of this, or just update the "How Does Reputation Work?" page, as this is actually asked quite frequently.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Meta sites *always* have the same reputation, Meta.stackoverflow.com site being the one exception.

Reputation is synchronized periodically, once an hour. This is [mentioned in the meta site FAQ](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

Your [Quant meta account](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5149/acheong87) has been synchronized in the meantime, and the reputation once again matches your rep on the main site.

Comment: Ah, makes much more sense, thank you. The synchronization part is what threw me off.