# Why don't I get reputation points on this meta site? I do get it on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, per-site-meta

I've over 500 reputation points on stackoverflow.com, and I joined meta.stackoverflow. I got the 100 reputation point association bonus. When I ask a question in meta.stackoverflow, and my question is upvoted, I got some reputation for meta.stackoverflow.

But I joined to writers.stackexchange and then `meta.writers.stackexchange`. I asked [question for documentation?](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/672/5190) on one of the meta sites, meta.writers.stackexchange, and I got some upvotes, but why didn't the reputation for `meta.writers.stackexchange` change?

I don't know why - how does reputation associate for the main site (for example: stackoverflow.com) and the corresponding meta site (for example: meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is... *special*. It has reputation. The other meta sites don't.

Comment: For a question from someone being surprised in the opposite direction, see [How did I start with more than 100 reputation on meta.quant.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178060)