# Reputation on other Meta Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, reputation, stack-exchange

I noticed that reputation from the meta site doesn't affect the site affiliated with the Meta. This is for other Stack Exchange sites. Is it supposed to be like that or why doesn't reputation get gained/lost in Meta sites affect the site affiliated with it?

IE: 160 reputation on Web Application and I asked a question with +1 score. Where does the +5 reputation go?

Comment: Also what may be throwing you off is a slight lag between site rep getting pushed to its respective meta site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178060/how-did-i-start-with-more-than-100-reputation-on-meta-quant-stackexchange-com.

Comment: Giving rep (probably only for use on the metas) for meta questions would probably encourage greater meta participation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the "odd" behavior of reputation on Meta Stack Overflow can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91333/why-do-i-have-a-different-reputation-score-on-meta-stackoverflow-com-and-stackov). The reason for this has to do with the history of Stack Exchange and how its various sites evolved, but basically the main thing is that Meta Stack Overflow serves as not only the meta site for Stack Overflow, but also for general questions about the Stack Exchange platform.

**However, this behavior is about to change**, as [Meta Stack Overflow will soon be split into Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own). As of Wednesday, they are planning to do this as early as two weeks from now.

Answer (score 2):

All meta sites other than meta.stackoverflow.com inherit the rep of their parent site. You cannot gain any rep or lose it. Meta.SO is different because it is not only meta for SO but also for StackExchange as a whole.

Meta.SO is supposed to receive its own meta site soon, but I don't think they have announced an actual date.

Comment: The split is always 6-8 weeks away.